# Regex to allow only negative number in decimals and 0

Tags: regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

Need a regular expression that allows 0 and negative numbers only. Below expression is allowing positive numbers also.

```
^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use an alternation here:

```
^(?:0(?:\.0+)?|-\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

### Demo

```
^(?:                from the start of the input
    0(?:\.0+)?      match 0, or 0.0, 0.00 etc.
    |               OR
    -\d+(?:\.\d+)?  match a negative number, with optional decimal component
)$                  end of the input
```

Comment: This matches `'0'` in `'00cat'`. The problem, as you will see right away, is that the anchor `^` only applies to the first part of the alternation and `$` only to the last part of the alternation. Headslapper, eh?

Comment: No, not at all.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you match with the regular expression

```
r'^(?:0|-(?:0\.\d+|[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?))$'
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/AFgwy5/1)

This matches: `'0'`, `'-0.123`, `'-0.000`, `'0.123`, `'-17`, `'-29.33` and `'-29.00'`

It does not match: `'00'`, `'-017'`, `'12'` and `'44.7'`.

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^                : match beginning of string
(?:              : begin non-capture group
  0              : match '0'
  |              : or
  -              : match '-'
    (?:          : begin a non-capture group
      0\.\d+     : match '0.' then 
      |          : or
      [1-9]\d*   : match a digit other than zero then 0+ digits
      (?:\.\d+)  : match '.' then 1+ digits in a non-capture group
      ?          : make the non-capture group optional
    )            : end non-capture group
)                : end non-capture group
$                : match end of string
```

Comment: @Tim, you must be joking. My answer certainly was not identical to yours when I posted, as yours was incorrect. Moreover, your regex still matches `'00'` and `'-017'`, whereas mine does not.